# OEToolchainConfig.cmake is not installed by cmake recipe Yocto

Tags: linux, qt, cmake, yocto, bitbake

I've been playing with Yocto in order to generate an image for my Raspberry Pi, also an SDK for cross compilation. I want to enter the packages to install in my image file and generate image using:

```
bitbake my-image
```

and generate sdk using:

```
bitbake my-image -c populate_sdk
```

The workflow afaik is that you source a bash file and environment is set up for the cross compilation.

However, for some reason **(Question 1)** `OEToolchainConfig.cmake` is not generated in my case in  `sysroots/usr/share/cmake`.

What I have so far is given in the following:

```
#To build SDK, use bitbake meta-toolchain or bitbake my-image -c populate_sdk

inherit core-image

# for populate_sdk to create a valid toolchain with qt5
inherit populate_sdk populate_sdk_qt5

##
inherit distro_features_check

DESCRIPTION = "My image."

LICENSE="CLOSED"



image_KERNEL_MODULES = " \
    kernel-modules \
"

#Framebuffer driver for tft
image_DRIVERS = " \
    xf86-video-fbdev \
"

image_DESKTOP_SUPPORT = " \
    packagegroup-core-boot \
    packagegroup-core-x11 \
    packagegroup-lxde-base \
    localedef \
    pointercal \
    xinit \
    xkeyboard-config \
    base-passwd \
    liberation-fonts \
"

image_BASIC_TOOLS = " \
    apt \
    dpkg \
    sudo \
    tzdata \
    dbus \
    packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh \
    xterm \
    networkmanager \
    wpa-supplicant \
"

image_DEV_TOOLS = " \
    git \
    cmake \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    binutils \
    binutils-symlinks \
    coreutils \
    cpp \
    cpp-symlinks \
    diffutils \
    file \
    g++ \
    g++-symlinks \
    gdb \
    gdbserver \
    gcc \
    gcc-symlinks \
    gettext \
    git \
    ldd \
    libgcc \
    libgcc-dev \
    libstdc++ \
    libstdc++-dev \
    libstdc++-staticdev \
    libtool \
    make \
    perl-modules \
    pkgconfig \
    python-modules \
    python3-modules \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    ccache \
    packagegroup-core-buildessential \
    glibc-utils \
"

image_DEV_LIBS = " \
    wiringpi \
"

image_QT_TOOLS = " \
    qtbase \
    qtwebengine \
    qtwebkit \
"

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " \
    ${image_KERNEL_MODULES} \
    ${image_DRIVERS} \
    ${image_DESKTOP_SUPPORT} \
    ${image_BASIC_TOOLS} \
    ${image_DEV_TOOLS} \
    ${image_DEV_LIBS} \
    ${image_QT_TOOLS} \
 "

#Maybe consider connman instead of networkmanager
#vc-graphics is problematic with userland..


## SDK stuff, to build sdk use bitbake my-image -c populate_sdk
# Add all static packages:  SDKIMAGE_FEATURES += "staticdev-pkgs"
#SDKIMAGE_FEATURES += "staticdev-pkgs"
#SDKIMAGE_FEATURES += "dev-pkgs"

# Dnf issue fix for nativesdk-qt add to local.conf
#PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_ipk"

# In the target side, add our libs
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " wiringpi-dev"

# Needed for cross-compilation / host tasks
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " nativesdk-packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-host"
#CMake conflicts with the qt packagegroup, cmake is a must, when qt packagegroup is nonexistent
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " nativesdk-cmake"

REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES = "x11"

IMAGE_LINGUAS ?= " "

LICENSE = "MIT"

export IMAGE_BASENAME = "my-image"


ENABLE_SPI_BUS = "1"
ENABLE_I2C = "1"

do_image_prepend() {

}
```

Which raises some questions:
**(Question 2)** I have seen some people don't use `TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK` or `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK` and some how able to add packages to the SDK. I want to know if I'm doing something wrongly. 
**(Question 3)** I have inherited some classes based on other entries but I'm not sure exactly what will inheriting `populate_sdk` and `populate_sdk_qt5` help me with. That can be a nice addition to knowledge if somebody could roughly explain what I am doing wrong and what can I do to make it better regarding workflow.

Thanks for the suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt to answer (Question 1):

My findings for poky-2.5 is that for my x86_64 target OEToolchainConfig.cmake is put in the dev-package (i.e. nativesdk-cmake-dev-3.10.3-r0.x86_64_nativesdk.rpm)

Hence, try:

```
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " nativesdk-cmake-dev"
```

Not sure whether this is a bug or not.